# Portable output to null stream in Fortran

Tags: fortran, dev-null

I'd like to implement a verbosity level flag in a Fortran program in the following way. The code would use statements

```
write (level1, *) 'This will be shown always'
write (level2, *) 'This will be shown sometimes'
```

and the streams `level1`, `level2` and higher would either be equal to `output_unit` or correspond to `/dev/null` (on Unix), depending on the value of the verbosity flag provided by the user.

However, `/dev/null` is not platform independent. I could try to detect Windows manually and work with `NUL` there, but I don't want to write platform-specific code. Is there a platform-independent way of writing to an output sink with `write` in Fortran?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I've made my earlier comment into an answer so we can tick this question off ...*

Fortran doesn't provide a platform independent way to send output into the void. If I wanted the facility I might write a little platform-dependent code, and wrap it into a module so I never had to look at it again.